How to select only necessary info in table extraction using uipath?
How to extract the only needed info from a web page using uipath table extraction. When I try to select the specific info the other unwanted info is also selected due to its similar pattern as the needed info. Is there any solution for this without using codings?
I want to extract data on various sectors from various web pages and convert the extracted data into Excel sheets and I want to do it without using any other data.

Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.

Improve your selector.
